# Cannot invoke 'getDataInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((NSData!, NSError!) -> Void)'

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm using swift 6.3 and having 2 similar errors

1. `Cannot invoke 'findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '(([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void)'`
2. `Cannot invoke 'getDataInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((NSData!, NSError!) -> Void)'`

Any ideas please?

```
import Parse
import UIKit

class UserVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var resultTable: UITableView!
    var resultNameArray = [String]()
    var resultUserNameArray = [String]()
    var resultUserImageFiles = [PFFile]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        resultNameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        resultUserNameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        resultUserImageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        var query = PFUser.query()

        query!.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

        //// here is the error////
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                for object in objects {
                    self.resultNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("profileName") as String)
                    self.resultUserImageFiles.append(object.objectForKey("photo") as PFFile)
                    self.resultUserNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("username") as String)

                    self.resultsTable.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return resultNameArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 64
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:User_Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! User_Cell
        cell.profileLbl.text = self.resultNameArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.userLbl.text = self.resultUserNameArray[indexPath.row]

        //// here is the error////
        self.resultUserImageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                cell.imgView.image = image

            }
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the declaration of the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock method from the parse header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first error is due to block parameters are wrong. `objects` and `error` both should be optional.

Like below:

```
query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

Second is same reason. `imageData` and `error` also both optional.

Like below:

```
self.resultUserImageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```

All fixed code:

```
class UserVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var resultTable: UITableView!
    var resultNameArray = [String]()
    var resultUserNameArray = [String]()
    var resultUserImageFiles = [PFFile]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        resultNameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        resultUserNameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        resultUserImageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        var query = PFUser.query()

        query!.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

        //// here is the error////
        query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects {
                    for object in objects {
                        self.resultNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("profileName") as! String)
                        self.resultUserImageFiles.append(object.objectForKey("photo") as! PFFile)
                        self.resultUserNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)

                        self.resultsTable.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return resultNameArray.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 64
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:User_Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! User_Cell
        cell.profileLbl.text = self.resultNameArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.userLbl.text = self.resultUserNameArray[indexPath.row]

        //// here is the error////
        self.resultUserImageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell.imgView.image = image
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot . It looks great now ,but there is other error shows up here       self.resultsTable.reloadData() said that does not have a member named 'resultsTable'

Comment: @iAli - that should say self.resultTable.reloadData(). There is a typo (resultsTable).

Answer (score 1):

In swift 1.2 (Xcode update to 6.3) optionals were changed, so now, the NSError is optional.

Which makes your function the following:

```
query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in 
    // Do whatever you want with these objects
})
```

Answer (score -2):

it works great now and other error shows up here

```
   self.resultsTable.reloadData()
```

the error  `UsersVC` does not have a member named `resultsTable`.

Comment: You define resul"t"Table above, not result"s"Table.