# How to set image as a profile picture from parse with swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, parse-platform

Retrieving text from parse was easy, but when I tried doing it with an image I can't seem to match the two types to make it work in any way. The code is as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var realProfilePictureBackground: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var realProfilePicture: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var realNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var realUsernameLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userFirstName = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("firstName") as? String)!
    let userlastName = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("firstName") as? String)!
    let userUsername = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("username") as? String)!
    let profilePicture = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("profilePicture") as? PFFile)!


    realNameLabel.text = userFirstName + " " + userlastName
    realUsernameLabel.text = userUsername
    realProfilePictureBackground = profilePicture
}
```

The strings work just fine, but the image gives an error: 
`Cannot assign a value of type 'PFFile to a value of type 'UIImageView!'` which i see makes sense but how do i go around that?

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```js
if let userPicture = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("profilePicture")! as! PFFile {
   userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
      (imageData: NSData!, error NSError!) -> Void in
         if (error == nil) {
            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
            //self.ImageArray.append(image)
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){() -> Void in
               realProfilePictureBackground.image = image
            }
         }
      })
}
```

Refer to this POST: [How to convert an PFFile to an UIImage with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400539/how-to-convert-an-pffile-to-an-uiimage-with-swift)

Comment: Then how would i use this code to to set it the the IBOutlet?

Comment: I assume the IBOutlet you referring is an UIImageView. After you get image from the imageData, then you can dispatch back to main queue. See Edited Code above.