# Getting data from Parse server into xcode

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-ios-sdk

I just got into xcode and swift using Parse.  I've created a view controller with an image view and some labels.  I also set up a Parse server with images and description of those images (for example: an image of a tree with a separate file of the description of the tree).  I've looked around and I cant seem to find an answer.  How do I upload the image on parse to my image view with the corresponding description of the image?  Thanks you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an PFFile to an UIImage with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400539/how-to-convert-an-pffile-to-an-uiimage-with-swift)

Comment: There are several similar questions in the site: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bios%5d%20%5bparse-platform%5d%20image

Answer (score 0):

Did you already look into the Parse Ios guide? 
I think that you have to implement the [Parse SDK for Ios](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/).
and then use what they say there [store images in Parse with swift](https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#images)