# Cannot invoke 'getDataInBackground' with an argument list of type '((NSData?, NSError?) -> Void) error

Tags: swift, parsekit

I'm getting the following error: `Cannot invoke 'getDataInBackground' with an argument list of type '((NSData?, NSError?) -> Void)'`

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761799/cannot-invoke-getdatainbackgroundwithblock-with-an-argument-list-of-type-ns), but as you can see the code does'nt work for me, here my code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
.
.
.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: resultsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! resultsCell
    cell.usernameLbl.text = self.resultsUsernameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.profileNameLbl.text = self.resultsProfileNameArray[indexPath.row]   
    //here error in line below:  
    self.resultsImageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in   
        if error == nil{
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            cell.profileImg.image = image
        }

    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid these problems in Swift 3+ if you simply omit the types in the closure

```
self.resultsImageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (imageData, error) in
```

In Swift 3+ `NSData` is replaced with `Data` and `NSError` with `Error`

Alternatively comment out the line, retype it and use code completion.

Apart from the issue you are discouraged to run unmanaged asynchronous tasks in `cellForRow` because the cell can be deallocated immediately.

And – as you are *new with swift* – please conform to the naming convention that `struct` and `class` names start with a capital letter (`ResultsCell`).